# Correct mysql column type for holding strings of 100k in length?

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which I need to store some serialized json strings (mysql 5). I'm not sure what data type to use for the column which will do the storing. The strings will always be less than 100k.

There are a few different text types to choose from when looking at the docs, is there one that is most appropriate for a string of that length? It seems like MEDIUMTEXT would be able to hold 100k strings?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MEDIUMTEXT column will be able to hold text of size 100K. I would suggest compressing the json data before storing it. That would reduce the storage size and would result in better db performance. If compressed a TEXT column should be able able to hold the data mostly.

Answer (score 2):

MEDIUMTEXT will work fine. According to the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html), the size of text types is:

TINYBLOB, TINYTEXT: 2<sup>8</sup>
BLOB, TEXT: 2<sup>16</sup>
MEDIUMBLOB, MEDIUMTEXT: 2<sup>24</sup>
LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT: 2<sup>32</sup>

If you compress as @Damodharan suggests, be aware that compression and decompression take time. Disk space is cheap.

Comment: disk space is cheap, but disk access is not cheap. In my experience compression/decompression overhead is lesser than reading large blobs from disk.

Comment: what if you want to search over those json values?

Comment: @DustinBoswell - I'm not sure what you're asking; can you elaborate? MySQL has wildcard comparison (e.g.: `. . . WHERE json_field LIKE '%Something%' . . .`) that work on any string expression (including text fields). Or are you asking about compression?

Comment: @TedHopp Yeah, I was asking about compression... or any other search-related issues that come up when picking a column type. (I assume searching over each of those 4 columns listed is equally fast?)

Comment: @DustinBoswell - The [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-compression-tuning.html) assure us that LIKE works with compressed tables. Unless the table is indexed (e.g., with FTS), the data will need to be decompressed for LIKE to do its job; whether this overhead is larger than the I/O overhead of reading uncompressed data is the question. I don't know of any studies of the relative performance of the two approaches.